# Trying to get DB2 to enumerate databases

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to use DB2DataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSources("db2.windward.net", null, "username", "password") to return all databases on that server. When I make the call it takes about 10 seconds to return and then throws the following exception:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 104.42.24.172:523

The documentation says:

> To be visible, the remote database server instances must have a
>   running database administration server (DAS), which is configured to
>   respond to Search and Known Discovery requests.

I'm assuming that is the problem. How do I set this for the DB2 server? We have version 11 running on Windows.

Comment: They've still not managed to remove the DAS? That's been deprecated for years now (but apparently there's no good alternatives yet).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to have admin rights on your computer and the use these instructions to create DAS:

> Enter **db2admin create**. If a specific user account is desired, you must use **/USER:** and **/PASSWORD:** when issuing db2admin create.

You can then see current config with command:

```
db2 get admin cfg
```

and update it with

```
update admin cfg
```

command.

**Sources:**

[1] http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0004960.html

[2] https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0005173.html

[3]
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002023.html